# Restriction of Cartesian product measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{X})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{Y})$ be measurable spaces.

We consider the product of the two spaces, denoted $(X \times Y,\mathcal{X} \overline{\times} \mathcal{Y})$, where $\mathcal{X} \overline{\times} \mathcal{Y}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{ A \times B \mid A \in \mathcal{X},B \in \mathcal{Y} \}$.

For a measurable set $S \in \mathcal{X} \overline{\times} \mathcal{Y}$ and an element $x \in X$, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) states that the following set is measurable:
$$
S_x := \{ y \in Y \mid (x,y) \in S \}
$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: This is a standard result. Let $u_x :  Y \to X \times Y, y \mapsto (x,y).$ Note for $(A , B) \in \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y},$ $u_x^{-1}(A , B) = \begin{cases} B & x \in A \\ \varnothing & x \not \in A \end{cases} \in \mathcal{Y},$ and since such products generate $\mathcal{X} \otimes \mathcal{Y},$ $u_x$ is a measurable map. Now $S_x = u_x^{-1}(S).$